# Is it possible to use DUPLO bricks in LDD?

Tags: duplo, ldd

Is there a way to import DUPLO bricks to Lego Digital Designer? Or is there another way to make DUPLO build instructions?

Answer (score 6):

LDD is a closed world where people can't add its own parts. If you want to create Duplo building instructions you should use [LDraw](http://www.ldraw.org/help/getting-started.html) that has many Duplo parts in its library, and allows you to create the missing ones if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no. Maybe they will add it in the future, though.